# pythonで行列を3次元のように２次元でプロットしたい。

Tags: python, matplotlib

python3.5を使っています。例えば３次元プロットを２次元に射影するためには次のようなコードで書けます。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f = lambda x,y: np.exp(-(x**2 + y**2))

x = np.linspace(-4,4,100)
y = np.linspace(-4,4,100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = f(X,Y)
plt.figure()
#ax = plt.subplot(121, projection='3d')
#ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,cmap='Reds')
ax = plt.subplot(111)
cs = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z,100, cmap='Reds')
plt.colorbar(cs)
plt.show()
```

これを実行すると次のような２次元グラフが得られます。
[image: 画像]
これを参考にして、ある行列を与えられたときに、行列の縦と横をx軸、y軸とし、行列の各要素をｚ座標の値として扱って同じような２次元グラフを書きたいです。次は試しに書いてみたコードです。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n_number=21
lam_number=21
mat=np.zeros((n_number,lam_number))
#print(mat)
for i in range(0,n_number):
    for j in range(0,lam_number):
        mat[i][j]=(i-10)**2+(j-10)**2

x=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
y=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
print(x)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
print(x)
f = lambda x,y: mat[x][y]
Z = f(X,Y)
print(Z.shape)


#ax = plt.subplot(121, projection='3d')
#ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,cmap='Reds')
ax = plt.subplot(111)
cs = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z[0][0],100, cmap='Reds')
plt.colorbar(cs)
plt.show()
```

これを実行すると、`TypeError: Input z must be a 2D array.`とエラーを吐きます。確かに、Zの形を見てみると`Z.shape=(21,21,21,21)`でした。

また、

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n_number=21
lam_number=21
mat=np.zeros((n_number,lam_number))
#print(mat)
for i in range(0,n_number):
    for j in range(0,lam_number):
        mat[i][j]=(i-10)**2+(j-10)**2

x=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
y=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
print(x)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
print(x)
f = lambda x,y: mat[x][y]
Z = f(X,Y)
print(Z.shape)


plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
cs=ax.contourf(x,y,mat[x][y],cmap="Reds")
plt.colorbar(cs)
plt.show()
```

としたところ、下のようにカクカクのグラフが得られました。
[image: 画像２]
しかし、より滑らかな図形を得たいので、やはり`X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)`を使って書いてみたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

０から20までを、例えば0.1毎にプロットする場合は、NumPyでは次のように書けます。

```
x = np.linspace(0,20,201)
```

そこで`X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)`を使うと以下のように書けます。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f = lambda x,y: (x-10)**2 + (y-10)**2

x = np.linspace(0,20,201)
y = np.linspace(0,20,201)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = f(X, Y) 
plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot()
cs = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z,20, cmap='Reds')
plt.colorbar(cs)
plt.show()
```

上の試しに書いた例では次のように変更すればエラーが出なくなります。NumPyの関数はベクトル演算をします。

```
x=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
y=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
print(x)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
print(x)
f = lambda i,j: (i-10)**2+(j-10)**2
Z = f(X,Y)
print(Z.shape)

#ax = plt.subplot(121, projection='3d')
#ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,cmap='Reds')
ax = plt.subplot(111)
cs = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z,100, cmap='Reds')
plt.colorbar(cs)
plt.show()
```

また、最後の例でカクカクのグラフになっているのは等高線の数が少ないためで、以下のようにすればカクカクはなくなります。

```
cs=ax.contourf(x,y,mat,100,cmap="Reds")
```

Comment: 我ながら分かりにくい質問だったのに、的確な回答ありがとうございます！お陰様で無事動作しました。